# Error Code: 1262. Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns 0.000 sec

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import csv files to MySQL.

CSV files that I am trying to import are 4 files from
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/lakritidis/identifying-influential-bloggers-techcrunch?resource=download&select=inlinks.csv

I wrote the code

```
CREATE TABLE inlinks (
    inlink_id INT NOT NULL,
    post_id INT,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    author VARCHAR(255),
    dates DATE,
    url VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (inlink_id)
);
```

To create table

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'inlinks.csv' 
INTO TABLE inlinks 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

But it keeps giving me truncate error.
How can I fix this problem?
Please help!

Thank you so much

Comment: Do not post external links, add a few rows of the csv file in the question itself

Comment: The lines are terminated by `'\r\n'`, not `'\n'`. Use a hex editor to confirm this.